# For how long is a W10 app certified?

Tags: c#, .net, windows, certificate, win-universal-app

I have worked on a Windows 10 UWP app for a customer. He provided a valid certificate and I signed the app with it. The app is not meant to be published on the Windows Store, it will be manually deployed to the client's devices (Surface tablets).
I am not familiar with the process of certification, and I am not sure if the app certification needs to be renewed in the future. The customer thinks that since the certificate is only valid for one year, we will need to go through this process every year. However, one of my coworkers says that even if the certificate is valid for one year, once the app is signed it does not need to be resigned as long as it is not rebuilt...

I have looked at the Microsoft documentation but cannot find a clear answer to my question.

Do I really have to sign the app each year ? It seems overly complicated to me...

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you upload your app to store, it will stay and install-able until it is put down (by you or store).

Same thing apply for your private app, you dont need to resign it each year, as long as you are not repackaging it.